# jquery Timer Functions

Tags: jquery

I am doing work on jQuery function, I have a one function the working while the mouseover event is triggered, but my requirement is it should not call while mouse hovering, it should call every 5 seconds, but I couldn't achieve this. How to fix that issue?

I have added the snippet for your reference..

```
f.children(a.childSelector).each(function(h) {
        jQuery(this).mouseover(function(i) {
                var j = (a.reflect === true) ? 360 - (g * h) : g * h;
            j = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(j);
            if (!jQuery.roundabout_isInFocus(f, j)) {
                i.preventDefault();
                if (f.data("roundabout").animating === 0) {
                    f.roundabout_animateAngleToFocus(j)
                }
                return false
            }
        })  
})
```

Comment: Give some html code as well, so that we can replicate the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
var repeatFunction = setInterval(function(){
    //do something here
}, 5000); //repeats after interval of 5 second (atleast)
```

Answer (score 0):

> it should call every 5 seconds

Use `setInterval(..)` or for more flexibility imitate the functionality using `setTimeout(..)`.

Something like:

```
f.children(a.childSelector).each(function(h) {
        setInterval(function() {
            var j = (a.reflect === true) ? 360 - (g * h) : g * h;
            j = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(j);
            if (!jQuery.roundabout_isInFocus(f, j)) {
                if (f.data("roundabout").animating === 0) {
                    f.roundabout_animateAngleToFocus(j)
                }
            }
        },5000);  
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery-Timers: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/timers

```
$(document).everyTime(1000, "tag", function(i) { // every 1000ms
   // do something
}, 200); // 200 times
```